# Error: missing return statement

Tags: return

My code was working perfectly before and now it doesn't compile anymore. I have searched for the missing return statement for a while but still can't find it...Here is the code:

```
private static boolean Prime(int x){        
for(int i=1;i<x;i++) 
{
if(x%i==0){
return false;
}   
return true;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you do not indent your code? You'd be amazed how easily you'd be able to spot the error. (Also, this isn't JavaScript to begin with...)

Comment: (To editors: please do not try to improve the question by indenting the code. The fact that the code is not indented is the whole *point* of the question.)

Comment: I'll indent my code from now on...Thanks

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058029/missing-return-statement-within-if-for-while

Answer (score 2):

shouldn't the last return be one closing curly brace later?

```
private static boolean Prime(int x){        
    for(int i=1;i*i<x;i++) 
    {
        if(x%i==0){
            return false;
        }   
    }
    return true;
}
```

and, as a side note, you could stop the for loop at the square root of x.

```
i * i < x
```

or

```
i < sqrt(x)
```

I updated the condition in the indented code block.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to see a problem if you use indentations:

```
private static boolean Prime(int x) {
    for (int i = 1; i < x; i++) {
        if (x % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
}
```