# "Missing return statement" within if / for / while

Tags: java, return

I have a question regarding return statements used within `if()` `while()` or `for()` statements.

As you can see in the following method, it is expecting that I `return` a String value. The problem is that if I were to use a `return` statement within my `if` statement block, the compiler would return the error `missing return statement`.

```
public String myMethod()
{
    if(condition)
    {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Of course I could change the method header to `void` and use `System.out.println` instead of `return`. But is this the right way to do it? Am I missing something?

Comment: What happens if the condition is not true?  What does your method return in that case?

Comment: You could return a default value (like null), if the value is not found. When calling the method you check if the value is equal to the default value and can thus check if the returned value should be processed further.

Comment: you should add a `return` statement after the `if` or in an `else` statement

Comment: Every code path needs to return; here the only code path which returns something is if `condition` is true.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing return statement } in java error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709459/missing-return-statement-in-java-error)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you put a return statement in the `if`, `while` or `for` statement then it may or may not return a value. If it will not go inside these statements then also that method should return some value (that could be null). To ensure that, compiler will force you to write this return statement which is after `if`, `while` or `for`.

But if you write an `if` / `else` block and each one of them is having a return in it then the compiler knows that either the `if` or `else` will get executed and the method will return a value. So this time the compiler will not force you.

```
if(condition)
{
    return;
}
else
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: I think overall he should just learn that he needs to put a return right before the last bracket of every non-void method. Because he is going to rephrase his question with that else surrounded in a while next time.

Comment: I'd say that using multiple return statements is not a solution. It is better to have only one `return` statement at the end of the function/method.

Answer (score 6):

That's because the function **needs** to return a value. Imagine what happens if you execute `myMethod()` and it doesn't go into `if(condition)` what would your function return? The compiler needs to know what to return in every possible execution of your function.

Checking Java documentation:

> Definition: If a method declaration has a return type then there must
> be a return statement at the end of the method. If the return
> statement is not there the missing return statement error is thrown.
>
> This error is also thrown if the method does not have a return type
> and has not been declared using void (i.e., it was mistakenly
> omitted).

You can do this to solve your problem:

```
public String myMethod()
{
    String result = null;
    if(condition)
    {
        result = x;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

That is **illegal syntax**. It is **not** an **optional** thing for you to return a variable. You *must* return a variable of the type you specify in your method.

```
public String myMethod()
{
    if(condition)
    {
        return x;
    }
}
```

You are effectively saying: *I promise* any class can use this method (public) and I promise it will always return a String (String).

Then you are saying IF my condition is true I will return x. Well, that is too bad. There isn't any IF in your promise. You promised that myMethod will *always* return a String.

Even if your condition is *always* true, the compiler has to assume that there is a possibility of it being false. Therefore you always need to put a return at the end of your non-void method outside of any conditions *just in case* all of your conditions fail.

```
public String myMethod()
{
    if(condition)
    {
        return x;
    }
    return ""; // Or whatever the default behavior will be if all of your conditions fail to return.
}
```

Comment: (Correction: this is NOT a syntax error / "illegal syntax".  It is a compilation error that has to do with semantics rather than syntax.  A "syntax" error means that the program doesn't conform to the language's grammar, but there is no production in the Java grammar that makes a return statement mandatory.)

Answer (score 3):

Try with, as if the `if condition` returns false, so it will return empty, otherwise nothing to return.

```
public String myMethod()
{
    if(condition)
    {
        return x;
    }
    return ""
}
```

Because the compiler doesn't know if any of those *if* blocks will ever be reached, so it's giving you an error.

Answer (score 1):

This will return the string ***only if*** the condition is true.

```
public String myMethod()
{
    if(condition)
    {
        return x;
    }
    else
        return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a return statement if the `condition` is false.

```
public String myMethod() {
    if(condition) {
        return x;
    }

//  if condition is false you HAVE TO return a string
//  you could return a string, a empty string or null
    return otherCondition;  
}
```

FYI:

[Oracle docs for return statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Answer (score 1):

Anyhow, myMethod() should return a String value. What if your condition is false? - is myMethod returning anything? The answer is no, so you need to define return null or some string value for the false condition:

```
public String myMethod() {
    boolean c = true;
    if (conditions) {
        return "d";
    }
    return null; // Or some other string value
}
```