# recursion for modular arithmetic

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to compute this:

```
x^y (mod a)
```

Using recursion as it works better for larger numbers. Here's what I have:

```
public int mod (int x, int y, int a){

if(y == 2){
 return x^2%a;
}
if(y%2 == 1){
  return a%m*mod(x , y/2, a);
}
if(y%2 == 0 ){
return mod(x, y/2, a);
}


}
```

The code doesnt work and another issue is the "missing return statement" error at the last bracket. What can be done to fix this?

Comment: There is no recursion in your code. Use Else if instead of last If,

Comment: Use `else if` and `else` to sort your missing `return` statement issue assuming y is always a whole number

Comment: @Rishi Goel there is recursion in his second and third `if`s

Comment: The method's signature says that an _int_ must be returned, so whatever route the flow takes you must be able to return an _int_. So change the last if to Else if as suggested by @RishiGoel

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Missing return statement" within if / for / while](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058029/missing-return-statement-within-if-for-while)

Comment: `x^2%a` does not do what you think it does. First it evaluates `2 % a`, then it does a *bitwise exclusive OR* (`^`) between `x` and the result of the  `2 % a` evaluation. Assuming you meant `x²`, try `x * x % a` instead.

Comment: What is the variable 'm' that is written in the your piece of code as "return a%m*mod(x , y/2, a);" ?

Answer (score 3):

In Java, a function, which return type is not `void`, must return some value. Unfortunately, the compiler isn't smart enough to understand that your `if` statements cover all range of input parameter's values. The compiler assumes that all your conditions can evaluate to `false`, thus making this function return no value on this case. So it cannot prove the function's correctness, and reports an error.

Answer (score 2):

Your last `if` statement `if(y%2 == 0)` is redundant because there are only two possibilities for `y%2`: it is either 0 or 1.

You checked if it equals 1, so if that condition is wrong, you don't need to check if it equals 0, it is definitely going to be equal to 0 if it is not equal to 1.

Remove that last `if` and it works fine:

```
public int mod (int x, int y, int a){

if(y == 2){
 return x^2%a;
}
if(y%2 == 1){
  return a%m*mod(x , y/2, a);
}

return mod(x, y/2, a);


}
```