# Getting a return line error for my method?

Tags: java

```
  public static boolean isValidDate(int month, int day) {
    if (month >= 3 && month <= 5) {
      if (month == 3) {
        if (day >= 1 && day <= 31) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      } else if (month == 4) {
        if (day >= 1 && day <= 30) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      } else if (month == 5) {
        if (day >= 1 && day <= 15) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Get these errors:not sure how to fix them im returning everything.

```
BoxOffice.java:81: error: missing return statement
    }
BoxOffice.java:85: error: missing return statement
    }
```

Comment: The error is straightforward: your method is missing a `return` statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Missing return statement" within if / for / while](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058029/missing-return-statement-within-if-for-while)

Comment: It is considered "bad" coding to directly return, maybe try using a boolean?

Comment: @JoshHeaps Says who?

Comment: @JoshHeaps I assume you are referring to [single return points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707/should-a-function-have-only-one-return-statement)? Sometimes it is appropriate, sometimes it is not. It's definitely bad (or, at least, unnecessary) programming to do `if (condition) { return true; } else { return false; }` (or `if (condition) { b = true; } else { b = false; }`), because it's just easier to write `return condition;` or `b = condition;`. I'd worry much more about that than multiple returns.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The best way would be more along the lines of `b = false; if(condition) b = true; return b;`

Comment: @JoshHeaps no, don't do that. The initial assignment of `b` breaks definite assignment; and it's just more verbose. `b = condition;` is easier and safer.

Comment: Oh yeah! I'm still learning the old ropes myself. I forgot about setting straight to a condition.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler isn't smart enough to deduce that the inner `if` covers every scenario in the range of the outer if. Just change

```
else if(month == 5) {
```

to

```
else { // month must be 5 here
```

Answer (score 1):

[shmosel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42566947/3788176) describes the problem and the least disruptive fix.

Personally, I'd write this as a switch, and avoid writing the long if/else statements to check the day:

```
switch (month) {
  case 3:
    return (day >= 1 && day <= 31);
  case 4:
    return (day >= 1 && day <= 30);
  case 5:
    return (day >= 1 && day <= 15);
  default:
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I wrote almost the exact same thing (you beat me by seconds).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yeah, I saw your answer. Sorry buddy.

Answer (score 0):

you need to transforme the `else if (month == 5)`  to `else` ....

```
public static boolean isValidDate(int month, int day) 
     {
        if (month >= 3 && month <= 5) 
        {
          if (month == 3) 
          {
            if (day >= 1 && day <= 31) 
            {
              return true;
            } 
            else 
            {
              return false;
            }
          } 
          else if (month == 4)
          {
            if (day >= 1 && day <= 30) 
            {
              return true;
            } 
            else 
            {
              return false;
            }
          } 
          else  
          {
            if (day >= 1 && day <= 15) 
            {
              return true;
            } 
            else 
            {
              return false;
            }
          }
        } 
        else 
        {
          return false;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Care to offer any explanation to go with this wall of code?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thank you for your remark.. response edited :)

Answer (score -1):

Try making a boolean, and instead of returning in the if statement, change the boolean and return at the end of the method. Here is an example with your code.

```
public static boolean isValidDate (int month, int day) {
    boolean result = true; //This must be set to a value to avoid compiler errors
    if(month >= 3 && month <= 5) {
        if(month == 3) {
            if(day >= 1 && day <= 31) {
                result = true;
            }
            else {
                result = false;
            }
        }
        else if(month == 4) {
            if(day >= 1 && day <= 30) {
                result = true;
            }
            else {
                result = false;
            }
        }
        else if(month == 5) {
            if(day >= 1 && day <= 15) {
                result = true;
            }
            else {
                result = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Or just remove the `else` and `return false;`

Comment: But then you are using a direct return. My professor taught the class to never do so.

Comment: Ah, the old Professor vs. Programmer feud.

Comment: See @AndyTurner's answer for an example where an early return is far preferable to a single return.

Comment: This isn't really fixing the problem - and by setting the result arbitrarily, you risk the compiler not catching the logical case that you might have missed, because the variable is now definitely assigned. By setting it to *`true`*, you risk saying that something which should be invalid is actually not valid (generally the less safe choice). It is better to actually work out where the return value is missing (/the variable would not otherwise be assigned), and fix that. Compiler errors are there to help you.