# Why doesn't the compiler throw an error saying "No return statement"?

Tags: java, return

I was trying to solve a [question](https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/array-and-string/203/introduction-to-string/1161/) in Leetcode, and one of the discussed solutions was the following:

```
public class Solve {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String haystack = "mississippi";
        String needle = "issip";
        System.out.println(strStr(haystack,needle)) ;
    }

    public static int strStr(String haystack, String needle) {
        for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; ; j++) {
                if (j == needle.length()) return i;
                if (i + j == haystack.length()) return -1;
                if (needle.charAt(j) != haystack.charAt(i + j)) break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Shouldn't the compiler have thrown a "No return statement" error here?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058029/missing-return-statement-within-if-for-while

Comment: No. There is no code path that results in the outer loop being terminated and thus failing to return a value. Now if the `break` terminated the outer loop you would have a point. But the only conditions that can terminate the outer loop are the ones that `return i` or `-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; ; j++) {
       if (j == needle.length()) return i;
       if (i + j == haystack.length()) return -1;
       if (needle.charAt(j) != haystack.charAt(i + j)) break;
    }
}
```

Here both of the `for` loops are infinite loops. The `break` statement only breaks out of the inner `for` loop. Therefore there is no exit condition for the outer `for` loop except the `return` statements. There is no path for which the method cannot `return` a value so there is no reason for the compiler to complain.

Answer (score 1):

this is because you don't specify corner values for loop counters.
if you add smth like `i<N;` or `j<N;` you would got compiler warning.
But till that it's the same as:

```
while (true) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first `for` loop is infinite for the compiler, we know it will return, but compiler has no reason to complain. Good question though.

Answer (score 0):

Your both for loops are infinite, the second one breaks or returns someday anyway! but the first one even has no break, then Java knows the you never rich to the last line.

```
 for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
      //Your second loop which is capable of returning or breaking (the second one is not technically infinite.
 }
```