# Java: missing return staement error? (Probably easy fix...)

Tags: java, return-value

Please look at attached pictures.

**The main purpose of SelectCharacter.**

 - General 3 in-game "characters" and lets the user select one by 1,2 or 3

- return the selected character (Archer, Ninja, Warrior)

 - This will then be instantiated in the Main class

Getting following error: Error:(32, 5) java: missing return statement

I've tried case statements and not too sure what the issue is now. 
Any Advise is appreciated 
if I've missed something please let me know and I can provide more if required :)

[SelectCharacter Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIT4Y.png)

[Main Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmhAg.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Missing return statement" within if / for / while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058029/missing-return-statement-within-if-for-while)

Comment: Please post code as text and in the question, not as a link and not as a picture.

Comment: Anyway, what if `input` is neither 1, 2 or 3? What does the method return?

Comment: And as a side note, in java method names should start with a lowercase letter (so `chooseCharacter` in this case)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca good practice! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not handling condition, when input != [1,2,3], say input =4.

Either make the last else-if in ChooseCharacter() as else only

OR

Add a return statement after your if - else if - else if ,returning a Person Object

Comment: Went with a else only, it will only be reached if a correct result is selected anyways  much aporeciated